# How to embed and scale windows in GNOME develop environment?

Tags: javascript, gtk, gnome

I'm tring to make a TileWM with some cool features. As I go through Gtk docs, I didn't find APIs relevant to scaling windows and embeding windows(can Gtk.plug make that?). How can I build that?

By now I'm using Seed.

Comment: I don't think GTK is the right tool to make a window manager with.

Comment: I tried to read docs about `node-x11` before I reading gtk's doc. But there was no simple API about scaling windows, which frustrat me a lot.